# SqlLiteDatabase.query order by date column not working

Tags: android, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm developing an Android app based on SqlLiteDataBase.
When I query the db using the query method, I want to order by a date column in ascending order.
It seems the ORDERBY is not working.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("myTable", // The table to query
            dbTools.tableColumns, // The columns to return
            whereClause, // The columns for the WHERE clause
            null, // The values for the WHERE clause
            null, // don't group the rows
            null, // don't filter by row groups
            "dateText" + " ASC" // The sort order
    );
```

The cursor mquery field during debug shows the following:

```
SQLiteQuery: SELECT dateText, <some other columns here> FROM myTable WHERE dateText >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00' AND dateText <= '2015-10-31 23:59:59' ORDER BY dateText DESC
```

(I removed irrelevant columns for your convenience)

After running the query, I want to check whether I have any entry, so I call:

```
if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
```

Then I do some logic and whenever I want to move to next row on cursor I run:

```
if (!cursor.moveToNext())
```

dateText column is defined as DATETIME:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE myTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, dateText DATETIME, <other columns here>)";
```

Can you please advise why the sorting is not working? The rows are not sorted when iterating over the rows on the cursor.
Example: 
if I have rows for 1st, 2nd and 10th of November 2015, the sorting by ASC will give this sorting: 10->1->2
Sorting by DESC gives: 2->10->1

Comment: what you mean `isnt working`? some error? or data isnt ordered?

Comment: I have updated the question. Rows are not sorted

Answer (score 1):

here what i propose to you to try :

SQLiteQuery: SELECT dateText,  FROM myTable WHERE dateText >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00' AND dateText <= '2015-10-31 23:59:59' ORDER BY date(dateText) DESC

and Be-careful for :
Dest ==> Descendant
ASC  ==> Ascendant

Good luck !!

Comment: Thank you. I need to write in Java, so I will put "date(dateText) ASC" in the order by param. Is there importance for the "Limit 1"? I don't want to get only one row...

Comment: sorry for Limit 1 it was put it by mistake, ! enjoy :)

Comment: note there is also datetime() for sorting by date and time, did  that solve your problem ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding date() around dateText seems to have solved the issue. The query seems not to be returning all entries I'm interesting in, but I guess that's a totally different problem I'll have to look into.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to order by a date column in ascending order

But your code show

```
ORDER BY dateText DESC
```

Change it `ASC` is default option, so you can remove it

```
ORDER BY dateText ASC
```